# socket_select AF_UNIX PHP

Tags: php, sockets

my situation in a bit confuse but I'll try to explain .

I write OSS functionality in PHP, the south interface talks to GPON nodes and north interface talk SOAP to the rest of the whole system.

Im writing now the TL1 interface to talk to a HUAWEI U2000 node that talks TL1/SSH to me and SNMP to the OLTs.

All the 32 TL1 connections are managed by n2000, and Im writing a server to deal with all the connection. I have solved the TL1/SSH connection and it works fine but I need to write the server to manage all 32 connections, queues, priority, etc.

One client (php script that came from and SOAP request e.g.)  can send a command array to my server and the server must execute the commands and send response.

This can block the server for the time the response last, but I have 32 possible connections so I implement one FRONTENDserver and 32 BACKENDserver. One client write a request in a AF_UNIX socket at the FRONTEND and the server send it to the free BACKEND , listen to other AF_UNIX socket to catch the response and send response to the top client.

Everything works fine but I have a problem:

I have implemented a test with 2 BACKEND servers, and put some sleep inside to simulate the blocking, and 3 client script, cl1.php cl2.php cl3.php with the same code.

when: cl1.php run -> BCKEND1 go to sleep 10 sec; run cl2.php -> BCKEND2 go to sleep 10 sec and when I run cl3.php the FRONTEND says "all occupied" until there is one free, everything fine... BUT

if I run cl1.php -> sleep , cl2.php -> sleep BUT in other tab I run cl2.php AGAIN the FRONEND dont receive the call , he wait until BKEND2 is free and then take the "other" cl2.php call again.

the other thing that confuses me much more is that if I run cl1.php, cl2.php AND NOW cl1.php?f=foo (or any else) IT works fine: says "all occupied" .

Is like if the script have the same name, the socket_select function is not trigger until the other instance is closed.

this is a resume code:

FTEND

---

```
echo "servidor FEND proxy tl1\n";


//socket por el cual recibo REQUESTS from client
$socketPedidosFile = "/tmp/php_socket/pedidos.sock";
unlink($socketPedidosFile);

$serverPedidos = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($serverPedidos, $socketPedidosFile);
chmod($socketPedidosFile, "0702");
socket_listen($serverPedidos);


//socket por el cual escucho las RESPONSES de los conectores.
$socketRespuestasFile = "/tmp/php_socket/respuestas.sock";
unlink($socketRespuestasFile);

$serverRespuestas = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($serverRespuestas, $socketRespuestasFile);
chmod($socketRespuestasFile, "0702");
socket_listen($serverRespuestas);



$clientesPedidos = array($serverPedidos);
$clientesRespuestas = array($serverRespuestas);


$conectoresHW = array();
$conectoresHW[] = array("ocupado" => "0", "id" => null, "sockFile" => "/tmp/php_socket/con0.sock" ,"cliente" => null);
$conectoresHW[] = array("ocupado" => "0", "id" => null, "sockFile" =>        "/tmp/php_socket/con1.sock" ,"cliente" => null);


//listen both sides
while(true) {

    $r1 = $clientesPedidos;
    //escucho pedidos


    if(socket_select($r1, $w, $e, 0, 500) > 0) {

        $client = socket_accept($serverPedidos);
        $comando = trim(socket_read($client, 1000000, PHP_NORMAL_READ));
        $n = "";
        socket_getsockname($client,$n);
        echo "FEND:recibí el comando: $comando $n \n\n";

        //este cliente tengo que guardarlo para escribir la respuesta

        //veo que conector está ocupado
        if ($conectoresHW[0]["ocupado"] === "0") {
            //mando ejecutar al conector 0

            //lo ocupo
            echo "ocupo conector 0\n\n";
            $conectoresHW[0]["ocupado"] = "1";
            $conectoresHW[0]["cliente"] = $client;//este cliente es el que voy a tener que escribir
            $conectoresHW[0]["id"] = "0";
            $comando0= "0-".$comando;

            //abro el socket
            $socket_file0 = $conectoresHW[0]["sockFile"];
            $socketC0  = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            socket_connect($socketC0, $socket_file0);

            //envio
            $buffer0 = $comando0."\n";
            $cantidad0 = socket_write($socketC0, $buffer0, strlen($buffer0));
            echo "mandé al BKEND $cantidad0 bytes por el conector 0\n\n";


        }elseif ($conectoresHW[1]["ocupado"] === "0"){
            //mando ejecutar al conector 1
            //lo ocupo
            echo "ocupo conector 1\n\n";
            $conectoresHW[1]["ocupado"] = "1";
            $conectoresHW[1]["cliente"] = $client;//este cliente es el que voy a tener que escribir
            $conectoresHW[1]["id"] = "1";
            $comando1 = "1-".$comando;

            //abro el socket
            $socket_file1 = $conectoresHW[1]["sockFile"];
            $socketC1  = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            socket_connect($socketC1, $socket_file1);

            //envio
            $buffer1 = $comando1."\n";
            $cantidad1 = socket_write($socketC1, $buffer1, strlen($buffer1));
            echo "mandé al BKEND $cantidad1 bytes por el conector 1\n\n";

        }else {

            //no tengo conectores libres
            $bufferEx = "todos los conectores ocupados\n\n";    
            echo $bufferEx;

            socket_write($client, $bufferEx, strlen($bufferEx));

            socket_close($client);

        }


        //echo socket_write($client, "$salida\n", strlen("$salida\n"));
        //socket_close($client);
    }

    $r2 = $clientesRespuestas;



    if(socket_select($r2, $w, $e, 0, 500) > 0) {

        $client = socket_accept($serverRespuestas);

        $respComando = trim(socket_read($client, 1000000, PHP_NORMAL_READ));

        //veo a que id corresponde la respuesta
        $foo = explode("-", $respComando);
        $id = $foo[0];
        $res = $foo[1];

        echo "me llegó la respuesa: $respComando $id\n";

        $clientEscribir = $conectoresHW[$id]["cliente"];
        $buffer = $res."\n";

        $cantidad = socket_write($clientEscribir, $buffer, strlen($buffer));
        echo "escribi $cantidad bytes en el cliente $id\n";

        socket_close($clientEscribir);
        $conectoresHW[$id]["ocupado"] = "0";
        echo "libero conector {$id}\n\n";
    }

    //flush();
}
socket_close($serverPedidos);
socket_close($serverRespuestas);
```

BCKEND:

---

```
//este es el conector 0, escucho ese socket
$socketEscucho = "/tmp/php_socket/con0.sock";
unlink($socketEscucho);
$serverEscucho = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($serverEscucho, $socketEscucho);
chmod($socketEscucho, "0702");
socket_listen($serverEscucho);


//para dar la respuesta escribo en este como cliente
$socketRespuestas = "/tmp/php_socket/respuestas.sock";


$clients = array($serverEscucho);

while(true) {
    $r = $clients;

    if(socket_select($r, $w, $e, null) > 0) {

        $client = socket_accept($serverEscucho);

        $comando = trim(socket_read($client, 1000000, PHP_NORMAL_READ));
        $foo = explode("-", $comando);
        $id = $foo[0];
        $com = $foo[1];

        echo "BEND:recibí el comando: $comando\n";

        sleep(25);//simulo la ejecutada

        $salida = "$id-esta_es_la_salida{$id}_del_comando_$com\n";

        //doy la respuesta
        $clienteRespuestas = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        socket_connect($clienteRespuestas, $socketRespuestas);


        socket_write($clienteRespuestas, $salida, strlen($salida));

        socket_close($client);
        socket_close($clienteRespuestas);
    }
    flush();
}



socket_close($serverEscucho);
```

CLIENTS cliX.php

```
echo "<pre>".time()."\n\n";

$socket_file = "/tmp/php_socket/pedidos.sock";

$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

socket_connect($socket, $socket_file);

//envio

$buffer = "comando_entrada\n";
socket_write($socket, $buffer, strlen($buffer));

$recibido = socket_read($socket, 1000000, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

echo $recibido;

socket_close($socket);
```

Any help or questions are welcome!

best regards from Montevideo

Comment: today I have done a strace to the process FEND and the SELECT kernell call is not triggerer if the script is the same.

Comment: so, if I run the clients from CLI it works well, seems like apache do somethig strange if the script have the same name.